# Looking for Burke and Scott Special Relativity Primer

Tags: special-relativity, specific-reference

I'm looking for William Burke and Peter Scott's Special Relativity notes. They are very useful as they use a novel approach to space-time diagrams. I used them long ago, but I cannot find them online anymore. The only references I found are these

http://physics.ucsc.edu/~drip/SRT/intro.pdf

http://physics.ucsc.edu/people/faculty/scott.html

https://scott.physics.ucsc.edu/

Does anyone have any information or link?

Comment: It could be he is planning to publish it as a book as mentioned on his website. So he has removed them online.You can contact him directly for the notes. I remember when Robert Klauber was writing "Student Friendly QFT" he needed undergrad kids to read his notes and suggest corrections.

Comment: Thank you, @ChetanWaghela for your suggestion. I just wrote professor Scott and he has replied saying that he is working on getting the notes in a little
more decent shape and that he will keep me posted on his progress.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I just finished updating the original version (from the 1970s!) of the Special Relativity Primer, so there is now a draft version available at https://scott.physics.ucsc.edu/pdf/primer.pdf

Please check it out and let me know if you find errors or have suggestions for improvements.

-- Peter

Comment: Great! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

@Dirac , presumably, you visited the parent directory 
http://physics.ucsc.edu/~drip/SRT to see drafts of seven chapters.

If you receive any updates, please add to your post.
( [Fingers crossed] I had emailed Prof. Scott back in 2015 and got a similar response. )

Here is another place that references "Special Relativity Primer"
http://pages.erau.edu/~reynodb2/ps250/ElementaryParticles_Relativity.pdf

(As you may know, Burke's
"Applied Differential Geometry" and "Space-Time, Geometry, Cosmology" discuss aspects of relativity... but I'm not sure how these align with "Special Relativity Primer". There are also materials on his archived website: http://www.ucolick.org/~burke/home.html http://www.ucolick.org/~burke/ )

Comment: Thank you, @robphy. I should kick myself (and I will) for not thinking about the parent directory. If I get more information from professor Scott, I'll post it here.